# Obsfucated code doesn't work

Tags: java, sockets, networking, obfuscation, proguard

I have a problem with an obfuscated program. I have 2 files:

- client.jar
- server.jar

When I use Proguard to shrink them, it works fine.  But if I check "optimize" I have `NullPointerExceptions`, and if I also check "obfuscate", I have an InternalError in my *client.jar* when it has to send an object to the server with the `writeObject()` method.

Please can you help me with the configuration of Proguard (I don't really know this tool) or tell me why I get those errors. Thanks per advance.

PS: I'm french so I'm sorry if I made mistakes in my explanations.

I tried to launch my client.jar with a .bat to see if I can see what's going on and that's the error I get when the client has to send the object to the server:
[image]

Comment: Open a bug report at http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?atid=474704&group_id=54750&func=browse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has few details, so my answer will be very general, but I hope it starts you in the right direction.

If you do any reflection to call methods, you'll need to add `keep` options to your configuration file.  You need to `keep` all the methods that ever get called via reflection (see [Keep Options](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoptions) in the manual).

For serialization, there is a [recipe in the manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#serializable) that should help:

```
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

Incremental obfuscation options will keep the obfuscation consistent between client and server; [see this section](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#incremental) of the Proguard manual.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help man ! I could have it to work keeping class that implements Serializable from being obsfuscated, but does that mean that I can't obsfucate them at all ? Or do I have to deal with options ... ?

Comment: Well, the serialVersionUID is the important part, I think.  As long as the classes are obfuscated the same way you should be fine.  What you don't want is for them to be optimized.  I'll edit the answer.  But you should probably use the same obfuscations for the server and the client to be safe -- there's an option to print the obfuscations to a file (say, for the server) and then use that file again on the other project.

Comment: I used the same options for both server and client, and I checked "shrink", "optimize" and "obfuscate" and it works.. I think I got the NullPointerException with the "optimize" option because I load images in my client using names of enums variables, so the names were changed and files weren't found. So I just made that it doesn't optimize enumerations and now it works. Thanks again for you help ;).